# Is there a better way to implement a function with dependent return type?

Tags: typescript

Using the conditional types feature, we can implement a function which has a return type dependent on the value of its argument:

```
function func<A extends "a" | "b">(
  a: A,
): A extends "a" ? number : A extends "b" ? boolean : never {
  switch (a) {
    case "a": {
      return <any>1;
    }
    case "b": {
      return <any>true;
    }
  }
  throw "impossible";
}

// using the function
// x is inferred `number`
const x = func("a");

// y is inferred `boolean`
const y = func("b");
```

The function `func` takes as input an `"a"` or `"b"` and will return a `number` if it receives the former and return a `boolean` if it receives the latter.

However, we have to aid the compiler two times because we are using `A extends "a" | "b"`: the compiler does not detect that the case is exhaustively handled (we have to add a `throw` at the end of the function), and the compiler does not simplify the wanted return type within the case expression leaving it at `A extends "a" ? number : A extends "b" ? boolean : never` instead of simplifying it to `number` or `boolean` in the respective cases (we have to add a cast to make the compiler happy).

Both problems seem related to the fact that the compiler does not fully reason about a type such as `A extends "a" | "b"`, it can neither find exhaustiveness or refine it in the case statement.

So my question is: can this approach be adapted, or are there better ways of implementing functions with dependent return types so that we don't have to rely on an unneeded `throw` and cast?

Answer (score 0):

While your approach is not necessarily bad, an improvement might be having two signatures for the function. A public generic signature that uses conditional types to specify the relationship between the parameter and the return type, and a non generic implementation signatures, which will be simpler to reason about by the compiler:

```
function func<A extends "a" | "b">(a: A): A extends "a" ? number : boolean 
function func(a: "a" | "b"): number | boolean {
  switch (a) {
    case "a": return 1;
    case "b": return true;
  }
  throw "impossible";
}
```

This will not enforce that you respect the relation between input and output parameters, but neither does the original. At least this version avoids type assertions in the implementation.